# Vector Stores storage in LangChain

Tags: javascript, python, langchain

I am working with LangChain for the first time. Due to data security, I want to be sure about the storage of  langchain's vector store storage. I am using HNSWLib vector store, which mentions it is an in-memory store. What does it mean? Does Langchain/vector stores store any data in its servers?

https://js.langchain.com/docs/modules/indexes/vector_stores/integrations/hnswlib
https://github.com/nmslib/hnswlib

Comment: [PrivateDocBot](https://github.com/Abhi5h3k/PrivateDocBot)

Created using langchain and chainlit 

It also streams using langchain just like ChatGpt it displays word by word and works locally on PDF data. ‍ 

code reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HNSWLib store data in the server where the project is host. So if you host your server into vercel then your vector store is running in memory in vercel server. You can test this logic if true when you execute `await vectorStore.save(directory);` which will generate vector files inside your project directory.